# Google Analytics: Event funnel with multiple events per session

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics

**How can we track bounce rates for event funnels with Google Analytics if multiple events occur per session?**

As we don’t have an ecommerce app (Web, iPad and Android), but an app where users follow the same process multiple times (e.g. 100 times per session), we want to see how often and where they drop out of the funnel per session.As each goal in a funnel is only achievable once per session, so we need to work around that. How can we track the bounce rates based on all events per session?

Example: 
Order of events in the funnel: A -> B -> C -> D

Event flow for one user: A - B - C - A - B - C - D (goal achieved) - A - A - A - B - C - ...

Funnel should look like: A (5 events, drop out 40%=2 events) -> B (3 events, drop out 0%=0 events) -> C (3 events, drop out 66%=2 events) -> D (1 event, goal achieved)

Now it looks like: A (1 session, drop out 0%) -> B (1 session, drop out 0%) ….

I found that there is an event flow report in GA, but I’m not sure whether that would suit my purpose. Does anybody have any ideas? And if it’s really impossible with GA does anybody know any alternative (free) tools?

Thanks a lot!
Lotta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/